# Error: Could not find or load main class discord.java.bot.JavaDiscordBot

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am creating a Discord Server Bot and when I build and execute jar file it says

**Error**

```
C:\Users\[user.name]\IdeaProjects\Java-Discord-Bot\target>java -jar "Java-Discord-Bot-1.0 V.jar"
Error: Could not find or load main class discord.java.bot.JavaDiscordBot
```

Here is my **POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>discord.java.bot</groupId>
    <artifactId>Java-Discord-Bot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0 V</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>discord.java.bot.JavaDiscordBot</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <version>4.2.0_226</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**Command for making JAR**

```
mvn package
```

**Output for packing files**

```
C:\Users\[user.name]\IdeaProjects\Java-Discord-Bot>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< discord.java.bot:Java-Discord-Bot >------------------
[INFO] Building Java-Discord-Bot 1.0 V
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Java-Discord-Bot ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Java-Discord-Bot ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Java-Discord-Bot ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\[user.name]\IdeaProjects\Java-Discord-Bot\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Java-Discord-Bot ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Java-Discord-Bot ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0:jar (default-jar) @ Java-Discord-Bot ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\[user.name]\IdeaProjects\Java-Discord-Bot\target\Java-Discord-Bot-1.0 V.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.535 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-11T13:21:58+05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\[user.name]\IdeaProjects\Java-Discord-Bot>
```

Comment: What does `jar -tvf` say is in your jar?

Answer (score 0):

Close your IntelliJ IDE and remove the IntelliJ IDE file, folder from the root of
the project.

```
rm -rf .idea *.iml
```

also, try with right-click on the pom.xml file and click Reimport. It worked for me

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/8953164